# Jquery conditional draggable with observable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm trying to allow an element to be draggable only if a certain condition is met.  Here's my code:

```
$(".folder-box").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });  // prevent this from being applied when some ko.observable property is true
```

I don't want to disable the element, I just want to prevent it from being draggable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a custom binding handler for the draggable effect to be dependent on an observable property. Fortunately, this is as simple as this:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if(value) {
                $(element).draggable( { revert: "invalid" } );
            } else if($(element).data('draggable')) {
                $(element).draggable("destroy");
            }
        }
    };
```

You would then use it like that:

```
<div class="folder-box" data-bind="draggable: yourObservable"></div>
```

Comment: Jalayn has the right idea.  Here's a fiddle to demonstrate using a slightly different version:  http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/ZVDMe/

Comment: Thank you guys.  I had to use 'ui-draggable' instead of 'draggable' for some reason, but it's all working nicely now.  Cheers!